# Taylor Theorem Demonstration step, book: Análise Real Vol. 2, Elon Lages Lima

Tags: general-topology, analysis

There is a passage in that demonstration that i dont get it. First Let put the hipothesis, $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $f \in C^{2}$ in $U \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $U$ is open, for all $v = (v_{1},...,v_{n})$ such that $a + v \in U$ and

$\displaystyle f(a+v) - f(a) = \sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}{v_{i}} + \frac{1}{2} \sum^{n}_{i,k=1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{k}}{v_{i}}v_{k} + r(v)$

we have $\displaystyle\underset{v \rightarrow 0}{\lim} \frac{r(v)}{|v|^{2}}$ = 0.

for prove we use $\label{1}\displaystyle r(v) = f(a+v) - f(a) - \sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}{v_{i}} - \frac{1}{2} \sum^{n}_{i,j=1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{k}}{v_{i}}v_{j}$ and

${\bf Lema}: r: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n} $ $r \in C^{2}$ in $B$. If r(0) and it's parcials derivatires of order 1 and 2 are zero in 0, then $\underset{v \rightarrow 0}{\lim} \frac{r(v)}{|v|^{2}}$ = 0.

the step's and dont get its when he tooks the parcial derivative of $r(v)$ and obtain

$\displaystyle\frac{{\partial r(v)}}{{\partial x_{j}}} = \frac{{\partial f(a+v)}}{{\partial x_{j}}} -\frac{{\partial f(a)}}{{\partial x_{j}}} \sum^{n}_{i=1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{i} \partial x_{j}}{v_{i}}$ and then again

$\displaystyle\frac{{\partial r(v)}}{{\partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}}} = \frac{{\partial f(a+v)}}{{\partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}}} -\frac{{\partial f(a)}}{{\partial x_{i}\partial x_{j}}}$

and with that we have the conditions to use the Lema. But how from $r(v)$ we get these two derivaties above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that any point $v$ (the small one) is determined by the identity function, that is $v(x)=id(x)=x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$.

Now, observe that $\dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i}$ are scalars, and the unique function depending on $x$ are de projections $\pi_i(x)=x_i=v_i, i= 1,2,...,n$; therefore $\dfrac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}=\delta_i^j$ (delta of Dirac). So,in the first summand we have:

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(\sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i}v_i)= \sum_{i=1}^n\dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i}\delta_i^j=\dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_j}$.

For the other summand, note that:

$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}v_i v_k=\sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}v_k) v_i$.

Therefore, using the product rule:

\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(\sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}v_k) v_i)&=&\sum_{i=1}^n ((\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}\delta_k^j) v_i+(\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}v_k)\delta_i^j)=\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^n (\dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} v_i+ (\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}v_k)\delta_i^j)=\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} v_i+ \sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_k}v_k)\delta_i^j)=\\
&=&\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} v_i+ \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}v_k=\\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} v_i+ \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}v_i=2\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}v_i .
\end{eqnarray}

Where, in the last equality we use no dependence in nomenclature $(i\longleftrightarrow k)$ and the symmetry of second derivatves (Schwarz's theorem). This steps help you to obtain the first identity (and please correct the one posted in your question ;) ).

For the second identity, work in the same way to obtain: $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_l}\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_j \partial x_i}v_i= \dfrac{\partial f(a)}{\partial x_j \partial x_l}$. I preferred to put  $l$ instead of $i$ for avoid confucion (becareful with the indexes).

Best,

ALAN.